# How get that step into (F5) work with Qt exec method?

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to debug with Eclipse a C++ application that uses Qt.

The source code of interest in the main class is:

```
int rCod = 0;

MyClass myapp(argc, argv);

myapp.processParams(argc, argv)

myapp.startapp();

rCod = myapp.exec();
```

Where:

```
MyClass inherits from QCoreApplication, that is defined on /home/myuser/Qt5.6.3/5.6.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h

MyClass::MyClass is the class constructor

MyClass::processParams and MyClass::startapp  are public methods.
```

When I debug this application using Eclipse and press F5 (step into) I can see the source code that is going to be
executed in processParams and startapp methods, but when the next insttruction to execute is
  rCod = myapp.exec();
and I press F5, I can not see the code being executed.

How can I solve this?

I have little experience in using eclipse to debug a C++ application and I really do not know if it is not possible to debug after executing exec or I am not doing it in the right way.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to look at `exec` function? It is basically just am event loop that listens for actions. If you are trying to debug your code, then put breakpoints in your code at relevant positions.

Comment: Is your question more generally, "how do I step into Qt library code while debugging"?